Change column name of a table
I am trying to change the column name of a table in MS Access using VBA.
Private Sub Change_Col_Name(Table As String, OldColName As String, NewColName As String)
Dim tblDef As TableDef
Dim fldDef As Field

Set tblDef = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Table)
For Each fldDef In tblDef.Fields
    If fldDef.Name = OldColName Then
        fldDef.Name = NewColName
        Exit For
    End If
Next fldDef

tblDef.RefreshLink
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

End Sub 

I get

error 3420 "Object invalid or no longer set"

for the line
For Each fldDef In tblDef.Fields


Silly me..
This one-liner does it:
Currentdb.Tabledefs(table).fields(old_col_name).name = new_col_name

You need to specify DAO, and you can't operate on a linked table. So:
Public Sub Change_Col_Name(Table As String, OldColName As String, NewColName As String)

    Dim Database    As DAO.Database
    Dim tblDef      As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fldDef      As DAO.Field
    
    Set Database = CurrentDb ' or and external (linked) database.
    Set tblDef = Database.TableDefs(Table)
    
    If tblDef.SourceTableName = "" Then
        For Each fldDef In tblDef.Fields
            If fldDef.Name = OldColName Then
                fldDef.Name = NewColName
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    Set fldDef = Nothing
    Set tblDef = Nothing
    Set Database = Nothing

End Sub


The main thing is to use a database variable, because the object Set tblDef = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Table) is invalid directly after the line has run.
